# Szőkefalvi-Nagy's unitarizability theorem in the Calkin algebra?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, banach-algebras

Here's a research problem, which I think interesting.
Suppose that $t$ is an invertible element in the Calkin algebra $\mathcal{Q} = \mathcal{B}(\ell_2)/\mathcal{K}(\ell_2)$ which satisfies $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \|t^n\|<+\infty$. Does it follow $t$ is similar to a unitary element, i.e., is there an invertible element $s \in \mathcal{Q}$ such that $s t s^{-1}$ is unitary?

Béla Szőkefalvi-Nagy has proved that it is the case when one replaces $\mathcal{Q}$ with $\mathcal{B}(\ell_2)$ (or any other von Neumann algebra, e.g., $\mathcal{Q}^{\ast\ast}$). I'm asking this question, because a counterexample (which I believe exists) would provide an amenable operator algebra which is not isomorphic to a $\mathrm{C}^\ast$-algebra---The existence of such an example is an open problem.

I will explain why a counterexample provides such an example. Let $\pi\colon \mathcal{B}(\ell_2)\to \mathcal{Q}$ be the quotient map,
$G$ an abelian group (which is $\mathbb{Z}$ in the above question) and $u\colon G\to \mathcal{Q}$ a uniformly bounded homomorphism.
Then, the operator algebra $\mathcal{A} := \pi^{-1}( \overline{\mathrm{span}}\ u(G) )$ is amenable. If $\mathcal{A}$ is isomorphic to a $\mathrm{C}^\ast$-algebra, then by the solution of the similarity problem for amenable $\mathrm{C}^\ast$-algebras, there is $S \in \mathcal{B}(\ell_2)$ such that $S \mathcal{A} S^{-1}$ is a $\mathrm{C}^\ast$-subalgebra. Thus $s \pi(\mathcal{A}) s^{-1}$ (where $s=\pi(S)$) is an abelian $\mathrm{C}^\ast$-subalgebra of $\mathcal{Q}$ and hence it consists of normal elements. Since $u$ is uniformly bounded, $s u(\cdot)s^{-1}$ is a unitary homomorphism. (The converse is also true: if $u$ is similar to a unitary homomorphism, then $\mathcal{A}$ is isomorphic to a $\mathrm{C}^\ast$-algebra.)

The obvious thing one should try is to see whether $H^1_b(G,\mathcal{Q}(\ell_2G))\neq0$.
For a starter, I looked at $H^1_b(G,\ell_\infty(G)/c_0(G))$, but it was zero for every countable exact group $G$. (Whether it is zero for every group $G$ is unclear.)

Comment: Great question! Is there any example of a $C^*$-algebra, where "uniformly bounded" does not imply "unitarizable" for $\mathbb Z$-actions?

Comment: I agree, this is a nice question because either answer would be interesting. (My money is on every power bounded element of $Q$ being similar to a unitary.)

Comment: (every invertible power bounded element)

Comment: I assume Nik Weaver means "every doubly power bounded element"?

Comment: Since this question has been bumped by edits: did you ever make any progress on this question?

Comment: Um, I posted the problem because I gave it up, and I didn't make any efforts. I haven't heard any progress either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Posting this purely so that Ozawa's interesting question does not stay marked as unanswered, and hence lead to unnecessary effort on the part of someone reading. (Note: could someone reading this **please** flag the answer for moderator attention, to make it CW.)*

---

It turns out that every uniformly bounded representation of a discrete, countable amenable group inside the Calkin is unitarizable. This follows from techniques introduced in work of Farah and Hart, as expounded in e.g. [arXiv: 1112.3898](http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.3898), which extend techniques of G. K. Pedersen for dealing with certain corona algebras. Details of the argument in this particular case are in Theorem 7 of the recent preprint [arXiv 1309.2145](http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.2145v4) by Choi, Farah, and Ozawa.